# Displaying a Carousel as a background in a div in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to display a Carousel component behind some text so that there are scrolling/fading images with a large header over the top.
I'm trying to wrap all of this in a div so that the carousel images aren't the background for the entire page, only this title section.

I've found [this post from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469705/bootstrap-carousel-as-website-background) but things have changed a lot. I've tried adapting it but it just doesn't show up at all, even after fiddling with `overflow: hidden` stuff in Firefox debugger.

How would I go about displaying a series of images (carousel) behind text, in a div, in Bootstrap 5?

Edit: here's the code I've adapted from the linked SO post.

```
<div class="col-xl-10 offset-xl-1 rounded">
    <div id="titleCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active" id="c-one"></div>
            <div class="carousel-item" id="c-two"></div>
            <div class="carousel-item" id="c-three"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h1 class="text-center">Title Text</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.carousel {
    z-index: -99;
} /* keeps this behind all content */
.carousel-item {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
#c-one {
    background: url(../images/front_2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
#c-two {
    background: url(../images/front_3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
#c-three {
    background: url(../images/front_4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .active .left {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: I've added my code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the fixed position in the `.carousel-item`s broke the carousels for me as they had 0 height, so I commented that.

The answer is like the answer for here [How do I position one image on top of another in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48474/16111494)

Basically, you parent container div `<div class="col-xl-10 offset-xl-1 rounded">` should be set to `position: relative;`, as well as the `.carousel`, both with top and left set to 0.

Then you make your Title row `position: absolute;` also with top and left 0.
That alone will work for what you want but will break bootstrap layout inside the Title row.

To fix it, also set it's `right: 0` (found answer for that here [Bootstrap container with position:absolute loses layout inside](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28144233/16111494))

Also, I tested a link in place of the h1 in the title to see if it was clickable and it was, so the z-index is apparently working and you'll be able to put stuff in the title row without problems.

Comment: thank you! that's exactly the gap in my css knowledge I wanted to fill.

Comment: Any thoughts on getting the background carousel to fit the text content? I'm messing with the height but because they're part of the same parent it doesn't want to shrink

Comment: I've kind of figured out actually, if you set the height of the `carousel-inner` div to 100%, you can change the height of the `carousel` div to whatever you want. For example, `25vh` to take up 25% of the screen. It's not perfect so far but it's working